# Can't login WSO2 API manager via wso2 identity server and Facebook credential

Tags: wso2, facebook-oauth, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

**What I wanna do is**:

1.SSO with wso2 Identity server 5.1.0 and wso2 API manager 1.10.0 (done)

reference : https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Configuring+Single+Sign-on+with+SAML2

2.Login wso2 API manager 1.10.0 via Facebook credential (fail)

reference : https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/How+To%3A+Login+to+the+Identity+Server+using+Facebook+Credentials

**The situation is** :

1.When I go to the login page of APIM , it will redirect to Facebook login page via Identity server.

2.I login to Facebook and then it redirect to APIM via Identity server.

3.APIM shows **Error 401 : Authorization Required.
The server couldn't verify that you are authorized to access the requested resource.**

---

***Identity server logs***

```
==> audit.log <==
[2016-05-03 01:34:56,770]  INFO {AUDIT_LOG}-  Initiator : sbyangtw@yahoo.com.tw | Action : Login | Target : ApplicationAuthenticationFramework | Data : { "ContextIdentifier" : "c2474e20-3b83-4007-b34e-a6c461f7b9fa","AuthenticatedUser" : "sbyangtw@yahoo.com.tw","AuthenticatedUserTenantDomain" : "null","ServiceProviderName" : "APIM_PUBLISHER","RequestType" : "samlsso","RelyingParty" : "API_PUBLISHER_ISSUER","AuthenticatedIdPs" : "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCAiYWxnIjoibm9uZSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJ3c28yIiwiZXhwIjoxNDYyMjM5Mjk2NzY1MzAwMCwiaWF0IjoxNDYyMjM5Mjk2NzY1LCJpZHBzIjpbeyJpZHAiOiJmYWNlYm9vayIsImF1dGhlbnRpY2F0b3IiOiJGYWNlYm9va0F1dGhlbnRpY2F0b3IifV19." } | Result : Success

==> http_access_2016-05-03.log <==
122.147.238.98 - - [03/May/2016:01:34:56 +0000] "GET /commonauth?code=AQBs01GQq0m76-z1ilUNzgIF-8qgBq7ES9MxIE_as5-EwoUg9kROlrKNQynM0xdZ7ZkdAMAxDq5wa8WRAZHoU8AHNTEHj_eEDzix5KKKyNTFkzqE0bRd4DXMaDwQg2r1WW9BTqVwAJYeJGuySE7aabNYfBaSyasqSOH0_kaow6-68MbDt6oAxCNBYUocn-JIDmS3-TUS6bYJsLMwYo8mcib22ZOl7pJWIhCPtx6mbIvcJmzIopdNqQwQkDMK741PN4jfNGfqkwkyRi1AQikgzomYSvqHt1slVV8KnHVDj-OTM2EwkDdVzWGiiyfKbT9P9MPZ7vxLYlkS6JgWdntzXDM7&state=c2474e20-3b83-4007-b34e-a6c461f7b9fa%2Cfacebook HTTP/1.1" 302 - "https://www.facebook.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36"
122.147.238.98 - - [03/May/2016:01:34:58 +0000] "GET /samlsso?sessionDataKey=a492a7af-202f-4370-af83-f96d8240f526 HTTP/1.1" 200 3632 "https://www.facebook.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36"
```

***APIM logs***

```
==> wso2carbon.log <==
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-05-03 01:34:43,373] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.realm.RegistryRealm} -  Realm service is not available. Make sure that the required version of the User Manager component is properly installed. {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.realm.RegistryRealm}

==> wso2-apigw-errors.log <==
2016-05-03 01:34:43,373 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-28] ERROR RegistryRealm Realm service is not available. Make sure that the required version of the User Manager component is properly installed.

==> wso2carbon.log <==
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-05-03 01:34:43,374] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater} -  Error when updating the permission cache for tenant : -1 {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater}
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Realm service is not available. Make sure that the required version of the User Manager component is properly installed.
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.realm.RegistryRealm.getRealm(RegistryRealm.java:149)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater.getAuthzManager(PermissionUpdater.java:90)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater.update(PermissionUpdater.java:60)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.util.PermissionUpdateUtil.updatePermissionTree(PermissionUpdateUtil.java:46)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.updatePermissionCache(APIUtil.java:4554)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_updatePermissionCache(APIProviderHostObject.java:284)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c1._c_anonymous_7(/publisher/modules/api/check-permissions.jag:169)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c1.call(/publisher/modules/api/check-permissions.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_25(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:83)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c1._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/jagg/jaggery_acs.jag:59)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c1.call(/publisher/jagg/jaggery_acs.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c1._c_script_0(/publisher/jagg/jaggery_acs.jag:5)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c1.call(/publisher/jagg/jaggery_acs.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c1.call(/publisher/jagg/jaggery_acs.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c1.exec(/publisher/jagg/jaggery_acs.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:587)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:507)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

==> wso2-apigw-errors.log <==
2016-05-03 01:34:43,374 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-28] ERROR PermissionUpdater Error when updating the permission cache for tenant : -1
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Realm service is not available. Make sure that the required version of the User Manager component is properly installed.
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.realm.RegistryRealm.getRealm(RegistryRealm.java:149)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater.getAuthzManager(PermissionUpdater.java:90)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater.update(PermissionUpdater.java:60)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.util.PermissionUpdateUtil.updatePermissionTree(PermissionUpdateUtil.java:46)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.updatePermissionCache(APIUtil.java:4554)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_updatePermissionCache(APIProviderHostObject.java:284)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c1._c_anonymous_7(/publisher/modules/api/check-permissions.jag:169)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c1.call(/publisher/modules/api/check-permissions.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_25(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:83)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c1._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/jagg/jaggery_acs.jag:59)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c1.call(/publisher/jagg/jaggery_acs.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c1._c_script_0(/publisher/jagg/jaggery_acs.jag:5)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c1.call(/publisher/jagg/jaggery_acs.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c1.call(/publisher/jagg/jaggery_acs.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c1.exec(/publisher/jagg/jaggery_acs.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:587)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:507)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

***Identity.xml***

```
  <JDBCPersistenceManager>
        <DataSource>
            <!-- Include a data source name (jndiConfigName) from the set of data
                sources defined in master-datasources.xml -->
            <Name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Name>
        </DataSource>
        <!-- If the identity database is created from another place and if it is
            required to skip schema initialization during the server start up, set the
            following property to "true". -->
        <!-- <SkipDBSchemaCreation>false</SkipDBSchemaCreation> -->
        <!--SessionDataPersist>
            <Enable>true</Enable>
            <Temporary>false</Temporary>
            <SessionDataCleanUp>
                <Enable>true</Enable>
                <CleanUpTimeout>20160</CleanUpTimeout>
                <CleanUpPeriod>1140</CleanUpPeriod>
            </SessionDataCleanUp>
            <OperationDataCleanUp>
                <Enable>true</Enable>
                <CleanUpPeriod>720</CleanUpPeriod>
            </OperationDataCleanUp>
        </SessionDataPersist-->
    </JDBCPersistenceManager>
```

***saml response from facebook***

```
    <saml2p:Response Destination="https://52.38.21.105:9443/publisher/jagg/jaggery_acs.jag"
                 ID="nfbjmnijblahmijdkcjolekcjnodibpjicoebece"
                 InResponseTo="ahnmgghndidhnoefdghpcdjiipifggdddnhiblej"
                 IssueInstant="2016-05-03T12:18:05.854Z"
                 Version="2.0"
                 xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                 >
    <saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity"
                  xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                  >localhost</saml2:Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
            <ds:Reference URI="#nfbjmnijblahmijdkcjolekcjnodibpjicoebece">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="xs"
                                                xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"
                                                />
                    </ds:Transform>
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                <ds:DigestValue>ggxLiK1EmD+McPcZeg1N83Fv9gg=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>CP2lIDldQ982Ipdr2L+lbX/heU170cY6mhmhxGNbPs80gn0dxLq/GjFSXiF8jPHjGgPVgnRR0YcpTtCLK9R0ApSyND+P4PgR7/diylqWJMx7t+U5317WYQF3eHabH2NgFvnSzKthjv1Pj3hjyBsobX3Y9gV76mH1yt5n5XZFaY0=</ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
    <saml2p:Status>
        <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
    </saml2p:Status>
    <saml2:Assertion ID="eadlilbmecplfedkihojbidmefiekgpihihgngbd"
                     IssueInstant="2016-05-03T12:18:05.854Z"
                     Version="2.0"
                     xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                     >
        <saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">localhost</saml2:Issuer>
        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
                <ds:Reference URI="#eadlilbmecplfedkihojbidmefiekgpihihgngbd">
                    <ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="xs"
                                                    xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"
                                                    />
                        </ds:Transform>
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                    <ds:DigestValue>ooEBywjtlX+KP3skLWU+Ug66gjQ=</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>G5KWqTchrtk4XSsAhDfhocIAguNVJdT25btnD4/OtFMBJ0jYYL/MnQO14eAdniPQ163ijPmgbh6GZWhI8FzpkXi73zPxVkiOLCO9LP7VJK4fjwEH+hrs5ukjKRfu1t5/aE08HwGjZXOJg6sKs00oXrWdm+a5UluyMndbuappbT8=</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo>
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
        <saml2:Subject>
            <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">sbyangtw@yahoo.com.tw</saml2:NameID>
            <saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <saml2:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="ahnmgghndidhnoefdghpcdjiipifggdddnhiblej"
                                               NotOnOrAfter="2016-05-03T12:23:05.854Z"
                                               Recipient="https://52.38.21.105:9443/publisher/jagg/jaggery_acs.jag"
                                               />
            </saml2:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml2:Subject>
        <saml2:Conditions NotBefore="2016-05-03T12:18:05.854Z"
                          NotOnOrAfter="2016-05-03T12:23:05.854Z"
                          >
            <saml2:AudienceRestriction>
                <saml2:Audience>API_PUBLISHER_ISSUER</saml2:Audience>
            </saml2:AudienceRestriction>
        </saml2:Conditions>
        <saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2016-05-03T12:18:05.858Z"
                              SessionIndex="f6348dd6-0c44-48c9-8d23-becbb07f61de"
                              >
            <saml2:AuthnContext>
                <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
            </saml2:AuthnContext>
        </saml2:AuthnStatement>
        <saml2:AttributeStatement>
            <saml2:Attribute Name="http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress"
                             NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"
                             >
                <saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                      xsi:type="xs:string"
                                      >sbyangtw@yahoo.com.tw</saml2:AttributeValue>
            </saml2:Attribute>
        </saml2:AttributeStatement>
    </saml2:Assertion>
</saml2p:Response>
```

I guess the error is related with tenant id and I found Identity server log shows **"AuthenticatedUserTenantDomain" : "null"** , but I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks

Tom

Comment: What is the database you are pointing to in your identity.xml ?

Comment: I let it point to external OpenLDAP in the user-mgt.xml.

Comment: I mean you Identity database, not the userstore, in identity.xml you can't point any ldap, you point to a database like 
<DataSource
            <Name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Name>
        </DataSource>
Can you share the corresponding configuration you have used in the identity.xml of your Identity server?

Comment: In your Service Provider configuration at IS, in 'Local and Outbound Authentication Configuration' section, select 'Use tenant domain in local subject identifier' attribute checkbox to be true and try.

Comment: "Use tenant domain in local subject identifier" and "Use user store domain in local subject identifier" default setting is true.

Comment: If 'use tenant domain' property is set to true, is should receinve username as 'sbyangtw@yahoo.com.tw@carbon.super', but you are receiving it as 'sbyangtw@yahoo.com.tw' Shall we check the response from facebook to your idp from saml tracer?

Comment: I don't know how to check it, can you tell me how to check it?

Comment: Install https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saml-tracer/ to your firefox, restart firefox, open tracer and then do your steps to login in firefox

Comment: There should be a different response as well for each request,as in http://picpaste.com/Screenshot_from_2016-04-23_01_34_10-KUeOU4bs.png

Comment: I update the response above. I also take the pic in https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-f4A2YGq-e2TU9GRzBadEZjMHM

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-f4A2YGq-e2TVllc20xc25TbkU

Comment: In user-mgt.xml and carbon.xml files of IS and APIM, can you enable email user name as mentioned in http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/10/07/email-username-with-identity-server/?

Comment: After I enable email user in carbon.xml in API-M , the login is working now.(Document just said enable mail user in carbon.xml in IS)
Thank you so much and then I'll try to provision user while logging via Facebook.

Comment: great to here that, I'll update my answer with it, anyway it should work without email username, if you have set 'Use tenant domain in local subject identifier' to true in your SP configuration. By looking at the SAML response you have attached, it seems like this property has not been set properly since your subject claim has send without the tenant domain.

Comment: Thank you very much and I'll try to provision user to user store while logging in with Facebook credential, maybe I'll ask another question soon XD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work once you enable email username in your IS and APIM as mentioned [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/10/07/email-username-with-identity-server/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the reason for the issue is, in your identity.xml of Identity Server is pointing to a different database than the AM_DB defined in the master-datasources.xml of your API manager. Then your API-M is pointing to a different set of tables and IS is pointing to another.

To fix this, you need to add the AM_DB as a data source in the master-datasource.xml of your Identity Server and in your identity.xml, include AM_DB as pointing data source.

Refer to Configuring Identity Server at [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.1.0+as+a+Key+Manager+with+API+Manager+1.10.0) for more details on how to do this.

Comment: The WSO2CarbonDB of API-M and Identity server are both pointed to the same Postgresql in Master-Datasources.xml coz of the SSO setting. Should I fix my identity.xml?

Comment: Point WSO2AM_DB of API-M master-datasources.xml to the same database.

Comment: What I have done is only Point WSO2AM_DB in master-datasources.xml to the database which WSO2CarbonDB points to in master-datasources.xml of API-M and Identity server. After this ,the error is the same as my question.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to reproduce the error "Error 401 : Authorization Required. The server couldn't verify that you are authorized to access the requested resource." by following the provided instructions in the documents. I have raised the ticket [1] to address/ get feedback regarding this issue.

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-4566

Regards,
Pubudu.

Comment: Thanks so much, and hope this issue will be solved asap.