# How can I set up WSO2 API Manager login with Github?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I want to set up WSO2 APIM login with Github.

I have integrated WSO2 IS with APIM and installed WSO2 IS Github authenticator, then followed the user guide [Configuring Github Authenticator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Configuring+Github+Authenticator) to set up Github authenticator. It works for the sample app which mentioned in the doc.

However, when I changed SP to APIM, I got

```
Error 401 : Authorization Required.


The server couldn't verify that you are authorized to access the requested resource.
```

Also I have read [[Article] How To Setup a WSO2 API Manager Store Login with Google](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2016/02/article-how-to-setup-a-wso2-api-manager-store-login-with-google/), it seems no more special configuration. Bad thing is I cannot connect Google, I cannot test it. :(

How can I fix this? Any suggestion? Thanks you.

Comment: Seems like this is the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36994534/cant-login-wso2-api-manager-via-wso2-identity-server-and-facebook-credential/, can you please check the suggestions given there?

Comment: @Chamila Wijayarathna I made the change, enabled EnableEmailUserName(APIM & IS), add modified some properties in IS user-mgt.xml, but got same error. I checked the log, not errors, just info `[2016-05-12 15:31:44,233]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater} -  Permission cache updated for tenant -1234` Please help. :(

Comment: It will be useful if you can add the complete log, are there any stacktraces?

Comment: please refer https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0RoflhhNCBCc0hYdVFOV1ZNU0E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I forgot update APIM internal/everyone role's permission, it works after I updated it, . Anyway, thanks for help me.

Comment: @Rory: It's better if you can add this as the answer and accept it as the answer, rather than have this details as a comment.

Comment: @DarRay, ok, I will add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the default roles of the user is internal/everyone, We can update the internal/everyone roles permission or change the default roles in user-mgt.xml

```
<Realm>
   <configuration>
     .....
     <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName> <!--change it-->
   </configuration>
</Realm>
```

and it will work.